# Recover data from broken ssd

Tags: macos, disk-utility, startup, ssd, data-recovery

**Prehistory**: in the morning I calmly worked on a laptop without failures, left it in sleep mode, after a couple of hours I opened it and saw a boot error (apparently it turned off and tried to turn on again). Before that, there was no evidence or symptoms that something was going wrong.

**What I have**:

1. MacBook Pro 15 2015 (512GB)
2. Some times it turn on and I can see my profiles and even can start log in process, but it can't be finish due bad blocks.
3. Through the recovery system, I do not see the disk at all, it is also not in the console `diskutil list`.
4. I can boot into the system using single user mode and see that the system detects a disk with boot errors.
5. I tried to run `fsck -fy` but the system hangs on one block for a long time and does not go further (I left it for about 30 minutes)

**What I want**: recover as much data as possible

[image: When I boot into single user mode]

[image: Error with fsck]

Comment: Find a local professional. You will need a specialist with the right tools and experience.

Comment: I hate to kick a man when he's down, but this is why people have backups. Recovering data from faulty SSDs is not always possible, and much more difficult than with a mechanical drive.